# How to remove all JSON attributes with certain value in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

given this table

| parent | payload |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `{ a: 7, b: 3 }` |
| 2 | `{ a: 7, c: 3 }` |
| 1 | `{ d: 3, e: 1, f: 3 }` |

I want to update children of `1` and remove any attribute `X` where `payload->X` is `3`.

after executing the query the records should look like this:

| parent | payload |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `{ a: 7 }` |
| 2 | `{ a: 7, c: 3 }` |
| 1 | `{ e: 1 }` |

```
    update records set payload=?? where parent = 1 and ??
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-inf function for this, but you can write your own:

```
create function remove_keys_by_value(p_input jsonb, p_value jsonb)
  returns jsonb
as
$$
  select jsonb_object_agg(t.key, t.value)
  from jsonb_each(p_input) as t(key, value)
  where value <> p_value;
$$
language sql
immutable;
```

Then you can do:

```
update records
  set payload = remove_key_by_value(payload, to_jsonb(3))
where parent = 1;
```

This assumes that `payload` is defined as `jsonb` (which it should be). If it's not, you have to cast it: `payload::jsonb`

Comment: A tiny error in the otherwise elegant function as you probably noticed.  It actually removes everything but the value as it is now.  Replace where clause with ```where value != p_value;```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```sql
update records
set payload = payload - 'x'
where parent = 1 and payload->>'x'::int = 3
```

Comment: `x` could be anything, I can't write a query for all possible keys. but thanks, this might help someone else